# AsyncTask android different arguments

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I am trying to download a file at android using AsyncTask. Because I want to download many files I want to pass the url of the file by arguments. Also I want to change the UI when a user clicks the button that triggers the AsyncTask. As I figured out, apart from the URL I need to pass and the Activity itself so I can have access to it's views so I can change them. And my problem is this how can make the AsyncTask take multiple and different arguments.

Questions:

**1**.The only way to do this I think is to pass as Object the first argument so anything can pass, right?

```
public final Example extends AsyncTask<Objects, String, String>
```

**2**.When I call the AsyncTask how do I write the function?

```
  Example a=new Example(??????); //I want to pass both a URL and something to give me access to the UI 
  a.execute(?????);
```

**3**. How can I use the "something" stated above argument to change visibility for example at a view?

Thx In advance for your time

Comment: Use the **constructor** for the Async tack then you can pass all.

Comment: @Tamilan Can you provide me an example or a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
     new Example("URL","something").executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new String[]{null});
else
     new Example("URL","something").execute(new String[]{null});
```

and `Example AsyncTask Class`

```
public class Example extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

            // variables passed in:
            String url;
            String something;
            //  constructor
            public Example(String url, String something) {
                this.url = url;
                this.something = something;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }


            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jObjOut) {

            }

        }
```

Comment: Please update the constructor (or class name) in order to match or it won't compile.

Comment: @Mario i posted the `Example Async task` class also check it.

Comment: @Tamilan ;-) If Mario needs to pass the URL only, he could use the first parameter of the AsyncTask instead of using a constructor and then passing new String[]{null} in the execute.

Comment: @Tanilan thx again it is a lot clearer now!I understood how it works

Comment: @fasteque yes but giving a broader example is even better. Now it come's to the programmer to adapt this example to his code!

Comment: @fasteque he need url and also something need to send so i gave just an examples.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind using `AsyncTask` is to avoid penalizing the responsiveness of the UI when performing blocking operations such as the file download of your scenario. When you use AsyncTask, the `doInBackground` method executes in another thread than the UI and the UI can not be modified from it so there is no point in passing any UI related data to it.

In order to modify your UI upon your background work completion, you can use the `onPostExecute` method. As @Tamilan suggested, you may pass the `Activity` object to the constructor of your `AsyncTask` if you want to use it there.

An example task could be as follows. Notice that you may replace `String` with `URL`, or even `Object` if you still want to pass different object types to the `doInBackground` method. Also, this example does not cover error handling beyond returning a simple boolean.

```
private class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{
    private Activity mActivity;

    public ExampleTask(Activity activity)
    {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // this is executed in a background thread

        boolean success = true;

        // do your background operations
                    publishProgress(50);
                    // more operations

        return Boolean.valueOf(success);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
           updateProgressbar(progress[0]); // update UI
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // this is executed on your UI thread

        if (!result)
            // show error
        else
            // modify your UI
    }
}
```

In order to execute this task:

```
ExampleTask task = new ExampleTask(anActivity);
task.execute(new String[] { "oneUrl", "anotherUrl" });
```

Comment: where is the onProgressUpdate() method  executed(New thread or Main thread)? I wanted to update a progressbar there but it crashed so I need to pass it as argument? right?

Comment: `onProgressUpdate` is executed in the UI thread like `onPostExecute`, so you are safe modifying your progress bar there (which you can have passed through the constructor or a setter). `doInBackground`is the only method executed in the background thread. Check the [AsyncTask reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for details.

Comment: @Mario I updated the example with `onProgressUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask takes 3 generic types:
1st is the argument which you send to execution;
2nd is for publishing updates on UI
3rd is for returning result
If you want to skip one or all of them use Void class:
example: new AsyncTask();

If you want to use your own constructor in AsyncTask you should define it in your own class that extends AsyncTask, something like this:

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

```
public class Example extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>{

private Object data;
private String data1;
private String data2;
private Activity activity;

public Example(Object data, String data1, String data2, Activity activity){
    this.data = data;
    this.data1 = data1;
    this.data2 = data2;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

    //Do here all your needs except UI updating
    //transfer data you need for UI updating like this:
    publishProgress("UI update data argument");

    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... arg){
    super.onProgressUpdate(arg);

    //Update your UI using activity 
}
```

}

To execute your Async task :

```
new Example(data, data1, data2, activity).execute(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameterized constructor to achieve the same. But be aware that if you have multiple arguments you would end up creating multiple constructors. Since you need to modify multiple activities in response you need to pass a context as well.

```
query = UtilityClass.getQueries(UtilityClass.CHECKRIDE, paramsList);
new Example(HomeActivity.this, UtilityClass.CHECKRIDE).execute(query);
```

This is how you can create a query/url and pass it to the AsyncTask.

A Sample AsyncTask :

```
public class Example extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String> {

    public Example(Context contextVar, int calloutTypeVar){
    context = contextVar;
    CALLOUTTYPE = calloutTypeVar;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "Loading...");
}

@Override
   protected String doInBackground(String...sqlQueryList) {
    String result = "";
    String sqlQuery = sqlQueryList[0];
    result = UtilityClass.doHttpCallout(sqlQuery);

   return result;
}

// Handle the response from the callout
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    switch (CALLOUTTYPE) {
        case UtilityClass.SCHEDULERIDE:

                ResponseHandlerClass.scheduleRide(result, context);
                break;
    }
}
```

I have implemented a response handler to handle the response from various callout results.

Hope this helps in handling your response from different urls.